# Unable to SET value from another class

Tags: c#, class, variables

Im trying to set LabelStatus's text to a message in the class but it doesn't work. 
Here's my code:

Class:

```
public bool openConnection()
{
    SetStatus("Connecting to " + Server);       
    //Mysql code
}

private void SetStatus(string msg)
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.SetStatus(msg);
}
```

Form1:

```
public void SetStatus(string status)
{
    labelStatus.Text = _status;
}
```

I'm fairly new to C# (php guy) and for the life of me can't figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: In `public void SetStatus(string status)` it's `staus`, but in its body you use _status...with an underscore...is it a typo??

Comment: You also need to call the `Show` or `ShowDialog` method on your form

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swcta4hh.aspx) or [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7c7daaw.aspx) Method on your form

```
private void SetStatus(string msg) 
{ 
    Form1 form = new Form1(); 
    form.SetStatus(msg); 
    form.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are setting the member variable and not the function's parameter.

```
 //try something like this
this._status = status;
this.labelStatus.Text = this._status;
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting `labelStatus.Text`, you're not setting it with the parameter you passed to `SetStatus(string)`. It seems like you accidentally used a data member instead.

Comment: @BenShepherd Could you explain, what do you mean, saying "didn't work"? What are you expecting? And what happens instead?

Comment: What is this `form` variable? Do you ever do anything with it? It looks like you're just initializing it and leaving it for Garbage Collection.

Comment: I am expecting `LabelStatus.Text` to change whatever `status` is but I'm not seeing any changes

Comment: That's because you're not setting it on your current form. You're creating a new form, setting the status and then leaving it to be disposed.

Comment: @BenShepherd And do you see the form itself? You need to show it with `Show` or `ShowDialog` methods

Comment: @BenShepherd Where do you call your `openConnection` method?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I think your class is change the status label of form label. To change form label text you need object of already opened form. define variable for form in your class.

```
public class ConnectionCheck
{
  private Form myForm;

   public void   ConnectionCheck(Form form)
  {
    myForm = form;
  }

  public bool openConnection()
  {
    SetStatus("Connecting to " + Server);       
    //Mysql code
  }

  private void SetStatus(string msg)
  {
     //Call method to change label text
      myForm .SetStatus(msg);
  }

}
```

Pass form1 object at the time of ConnectionCheck object creation from from1 codebehind(form1.cs).

```
ConnectionCheck connection = new ConnectionCheck(this);
```

And Also, change _status to parameter variable.

```
public void SetStatus(string status)
{
    labelStatus.Text = status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the names : try to make them same, see

```
labelStatus.Text = **status**;
```